# Scp from a server accessible via another server

Tags: linux, scp

For a security challenge I have to exploit a buffer overflow. I just have the executable file. To access the challenge, I have to go on a secure server, that I will call the first server. Here "scp" is not working and I cannot install it because I don't have any privileges. Then I go in another server, the second server, only accessible from the first server. Here is the executable.

The problem is I want to use radare2 which is not installed here, so I want to transfer this file on my local machine to work on it.

So what I wanted to do is to scp from the first server to get the file on the second server, and then scp on my local machine to get the file back from the first server. But the problem is that scp is not installed on the first server.

Would you have an idea on how I could do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for http://serverfault.com/ than for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scp is just copying over ssh - but as IIRC it can be disabled in the server config.

As the other answer referenced, a ssh tunnel would do the trick.

```
you@yourmachine:~$ ssh -L2222:server2:22 user@server1
```

You are now on server1, and anything sent from your localhost:2222 will go over your SSH connection and then after decryption will be forwarded to server2 port 22 (default for ssh).

Open a new terminal and

```
you@yourmachine:~$ ssh -p 2222 username-on-server2@localhost
```

or

```
you@yourmachine:~$ scp -P 2222 localfile username-on-server2@localhost:/path/on/server2/to/save/it/in
```

Your second ssh client process will connect on port 2222 of your localhost, slip into the ssh tunnel and be sent to server1 where it will then be forwarded on to server2, who will see it as an incoming connection from server1.